# Exception not intercepted by try: except:

Tags: python, exception

I created an app that heavily relies on asyncio, and which uses additional third party library that also relies on asyncio (to deal with websockets).

With few websockets opened, my code works fine. When I increase the number of websockets I start having some exceptions. In order to debug the anomaly, I tried to surround the lines within my code that generates the exception with a `try:` `except ValueError:` and put a breakpoint in the except part.

For instance, the here under exception was raised

```
Exception in callback AsyncIOEventEmitter._emit_run.<locals>._callback(<Task finishe...id indices',)>) at [XXX]\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyee-8.1.0-py3.6.egg\pyee\_asyncio.py:55
handle: <Handle AsyncIOEventEmitter._emit_run.<locals>._callback(<Task finishe...id indices',)>) at [XXX]\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyee-8.1.0-py3.6.egg\pyee\_asyncio.py:55>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[XXX]\Python36\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "[XXX]\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyee-8.1.0-py3.6.egg\pyee\_asyncio.py", line 62, in _callback
    self.emit('error', exc)
  File "[XXX]\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyee-8.1.0-py3.6.egg\pyee\_base.py", line 116, in emit
    self._emit_handle_potential_error(event, args[0] if args else None)
  File "[XXX]\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyee-8.1.0-py3.6.egg\pyee\_base.py", line 86, in _emit_handle_potential_error
    raise error
  File "[XXX]\arbitrager.py", line 48, in order_book_update
    opportunity_update(data, False)
  File "[XXX]\arbitrager.py", line 62, in opportunity_update
    np.where(symbols.paths['symbol4'] == data['symbol'])[0],
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

So I updated my code and ended up with something like:

```
try:
    index = np.unique(np.concatenate([
        index,
        np.where(symbols.paths['symbol1'] == data['symbol'])[0],
        np.where(symbols.paths['symbol2'] == data['symbol'])[0],
        np.where(symbols.paths['symbol3'] == data['symbol'])[0],
        np.where(symbols.paths['symbol4'] == data['symbol'])[0],
        np.where(symbols.paths['symbol5'] == data['symbol'])[0]
    ]))
except ValueError:
    print("oups") #put a breakpoint here
```

When I run again my code I still have exceptions raised at the same moment, without triggering the break point

Any idea why the exception is not catch by the `try:` `except:`?
Note that I am not asking for some help on the meaning of the exception, I just want to access the breakpoint so I can debug the values.

Comment: Your `except` catches `ValueError`, but the code under `try` raises `IndexError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmm, seems like you are excepting `ValueError`.

```
except ValueError:
    print("oups")
```

But your error is `IndexError`. So the obvious change would be to correct your except.

```
except IndexError:
    print("oups")
```

Additionally, if you ever want to know what error is occurring, you can use something like below.

```
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e).__name__)
```

Based on the output you can change what error you want to accept.